# SQLAlchemy filter converting datetime.time to datetime.datetime

Tags: python, sql-server, datetime, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy and cannot for the life of me get it to filter a TIME column without treating it as a DATETIME.

I have the class defined as

```
class v_MyView(Base):
  __table__ = Table('MyView', Base.metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('EntryDateTime', DateTime),
    Column('EntryDate', Date),
    Column('EntryTime', Time),
    ...
```

If I do this

```
results = db.query(v_MyView).first()
print(results.EntryTime)
```

I get `datetime.time(15, 30, 22, 560000)` as expected

However if I do this

```
results = db.query(v_MyView).filter(v_MyView.EntryTime >= datetime.time(5,0)).first()
print(results.EntryTime)
```

I get an error

```
[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The data types time and datetime2 
are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator. (402) (SQLExecDirectW)
```

And looking at the generated query, I see

```
WHERE [v_MyView].[EntryTime] >= ?]
[parameters: (datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 5, 0),)]
```

Examining the filter it appears to be generated correctly

```
right: BindParameter('%(140718484304128 EntryTime)s', datetime.time(5, 0), type_=Time())
```

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This has been accepted as a bug in the [SQLAlchemy repo](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5339)

short term solution is to use cast:

```
from sqlalchemy import cast
query.filter(my_column >= cast(datetime.time(5, 0), TIME))
```